# How to get data of transaction from Relay Response URL (SIM) Authorize.Net asp.net but it says this kind of request is not supported ??

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net, sim-card

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll");
        byte[] param = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("x_login=5RV7a3kUww&x_tran_key=4SzL379Tbc7Nt4MP");
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        // append PayPal verification code to end of string    

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //     req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(authKey)));
        //  req.Headers.Add("name","value");
        // send data back to PayPal to request verification
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        // receive response from PayPal
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Relay Response is used with the Server Integrated Method (SIM) API. That's their hosted payment form. You're not using SIM in the code you posted. It looks like you're using the Advanced Integration Method (AIM) API. AIM does not work with Relay Response because you don't need it since the user never leaves your site.

I also see comments mentioning Paypal which makes absolutely no sense. I'm not sure why that's even there.

Comment: No i 'm using SIM  and relay response url not working properly .. i mean how to get transaction details after succesful transaction on SIM?if u have any idea to retrive transaction then plz provide me code details..

Comment: Your code that you posted is **not** how you use SIM. It's how you use AIM. I strongly recommend you check out their [sample code](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/).